# ‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘linux’

Tags: jenkins

When the job starts getting this message, how can I fix that, also with docker label, why my jenkins cannot find lables? Do I need to configure them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to wait a little bit and this error get eliminated

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you're expecting an external agent to handle the master/slave work, you'd better make sure it does not require an extra cloud config such as Jenkins URL and/or tunnel to handle it for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).